# SQL Server Date Format India to US

Tags: sql, sql-server, date-format, simpledateformat

I've a service which push date from my SQL server database to web database and the date format that is pushed is "yyyyMMdd".

My database resides in india, so date format and current date is based on Indian Culture and Locale based.

And my web server resided in US, so there the date format is based on US.

**There is almost 13 hours difference in Indian and US time. So when my client entered a consignment on say 13 June 2011 9:00 am in the morning, it shows on website that is received on  12th June.**

So receiving a consignment before client even booked them makes such a big hassle. Please guide me for something to reolve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will take the user input and convert it to UTC:

```
DECLARE @input DateTime = '13 June 2011 9:00 am';
DECLARE @utc DateTime = DATEADD(s, DATEDIFF(s, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), @input);

SELECT @input UserInput, @utc UTC;
```

You can store all `DateTime` values in your database as UTC and then present them to the user in whichever timezone / culture is appropriate.

Comment: I tried your suggested approach, I don't understand it yet. But it works like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The transaction did actually happen on the 12th of June in the USA, so that is actually correct.

If you want that date to show 12th of june when viewed in the USA and the 13th of June when viewed in India you need to store your dates as UTC dates.